# Dynamic Array in C++ Class

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to do a dynamic array with my class. You see I want to type in 2 user with their info and then display it. I got the whole class set up with the input and output operators already overloaded. How can I build up a dynamical array inside the class and input data to it and then display it? I may have to use the [] operator, that is already overloaded, inside the friend functions?

Here is the class:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Payroll {
private:

    int empNumber;
    string name;
    T hours;
    T payRate;
    T grossPay;

    T *aptr;
    int arraySize;

public:

    Payroll(int size);
    Payroll();
    Payroll(const Payroll & aPayroll);
    ~Payroll();

    //Mutators

    void setEmpNumber(int empNumber);

    void setName(string name);

    void setHours(T hours);

    void setPayRate(T payRate);

    void setGrossPay(T grossPay);
    //Accessors

    int getEmpNumber()const;

    string getName()const;

    T getHours()const;

    T getPayRate()const;

    T getGrossPay()const;

    friend ostream & operator << <>(ostream & output, const Payroll & aPayroll);

    friend istream & operator >> <>(istream & input, Payroll & aPayroll);

    T &operator[](int);

};

template <class T>
Payroll<T>::Payroll(int size) {



    arraySize = size;
    aptr = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        aptr[i] = T();


}

template <class T>
Payroll<T>::Payroll() : empNumber(0), name(""), hours(0.00), payRate(0.00), grossPay(0.00) {}

template <class T>
Payroll<T>::Payroll(const Payroll & aPayroll) : empNumber(aPayroll.empNumber), name(aPayroll.name), hours(aPayroll.hours),
payRate(aPayroll.payRate), grossPay(aPayroll.grossPay) {

    arraySize = aPayroll.arraySize;
    aptr = new T[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        aptr[i] = aPayroll[i];

}



template <class T>
Payroll<T>::~Payroll() {

    if (arraySize > 0)
        delete[] aptr;
}

//Mutators

template <class T>
void Payroll<T>::setEmpNumber(int empNumber) {
    this->empNumber = empNumber;
}

template <class T>
void Payroll<T>::setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

template <class T>
void Payroll<T>::setHours(T hours) {
    this->hours = hours;
}

template <class T>
void Payroll<T>::setPayRate(T payRate) {
    this->payRate = payRate;
}

template <class T>
void Payroll<T>::setGrossPay(T grossPay) {
    this->grossPay = grossPay;
}

//Accessors

template <class T>
int Payroll<T>::getEmpNumber()const {
    return(this->empNumber);
}

template <class T>
string Payroll<T>::getName()const {
    return(this->name);
}

template <class T>
T Payroll<T>::getHours()const {
    return(this->hours);
}

template <class T>
T Payroll<T>::getPayRate()const {
    return(this->payRate);
}

template <class T>
T Payroll<T>::getGrossPay()const {
    return(this->grossPay);
}

template <class T>
ostream & operator << (ostream & output, const Payroll<T> & aPayroll) {

    for (int i = 0; i < aPayroll.arraySize; i++) {
        output << "Employee Number: " << aPayroll.empNumber;
        output << "\nEmployee Name: " << aPayroll.name;
        output << "\nHours Worked: " << aPayroll.hours;
        output << "\nPay Rate: " << aPayroll.payRate;
        output << "\nGross Pay: " << aPayroll.grossPay << endl;
    }

    return output;
}

template <class T>
istream & operator >>(istream & input, Payroll<T> & aPayroll) {

    for (int i = 0; i < aPayroll.arraySize; i++) {

        cout << "Please enter Employee Number: ";
        input >> aPayroll.empNumber;

        cout << "Please enter Employee Name: ";
        input >> aPayroll.name;

        cout << "Please enter Hours Worked: ";
        input >> aPayroll.hours;

        cout << "Please enter Pay Rate: ";
        input >> aPayroll.payRate;

        cout << "Please enter Gross Pay: ";
        input >> aPayroll.grossPay;

        cout << endl;
    }
    return input;
}

template <class T>
T &Payroll<T>::operator[](int position) {

    return aptr[position];
}
```

And here is the main:

```
int main(){ 


    Payroll <int> employee(2);


        cin >> employee;

        cout << employee;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to use a dynamic array in C++ (unless this is homework). Step 1, use `std::vector`. Step 2: there is no step 2.

Comment: Yeah this is homework and I can't use Vectors. Is there any way?

Comment: Are you allowed to re-invent a simplified version of `std::vector` instead of embedding the array to your class? It is too difficult to use dynamic array without a dedicated wrapper class around it.

Comment: If by re-inventing the std::vector Ive to use dynamic array then I yeah. How can I do that? Ive never use vectors.

Comment: The point is, instead of doing all the memory management in the `PayRoll` class (and then repeating it in other classes that need the same thing), make your own `template <typename> class dynamic_array`, *then* use that in `PayRoll`.